# How do I submit form data after another hook is set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When a user submits a form, I have to show a modal asking them to connect if they haven't yet. On success, the modal sets the user data in a hook, and then I continue with the submission flow.

So there are 2 conditions to submit:

1. User submits form (clicks button)
2. User data is set

I solved it reactively, using an effect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function nestedAsync() {
    if (userData && pendingSubmitIntent) {
      pendingSubmitIntent(false);
      await submit(
        formData, // simplified - this is actually several hooks
        userData
      );
    }
  }
  nestedAsync();
}, [pendingSubmitIntent, userData]);
```

And the submit click handler:

```js
setPendingSubmitIntent(true);
if (!userData) {
  setShowConnectModal(true);
}
```

The modal is in the component:

```js
{setShowConnectModal && (
  <ConnectModal
    setUserData={setUserData}
  />
)}
```

This actually works, but I'm getting a warning that I'm not declaring `formData` in the dependencies array. I can't do this, because otherwise the effect will be called when editing the inputs and that's not correct. The effect has to be called only when submitting.

And this warning makes me think that there's something fundamentally wrong with this approach. A state machine comes to mind, but I feel that it should be simpler. Any ideas?

Comment: We decided to disable these warnings, since we have specific variables that we did not want to re-run the useEffect when modified. You might want to look up this warning and see if there are some design-patters worth following to keep this rule active.

Comment: Show all of the code, especially the hooks creating `formData`.

Comment: In `ConnectModal` when do you call `setUserData`? Do you have some kind of event handler in there also?

Comment: Also, what is `formData`? Is it state? And if so, is that state used in the UI?

Comment: @NickParsons it's called in an event handler (by a third party), after the connection process is finished (sorry for the late reply. I'll go through your reply soon).

Comment: @morganney @NickParsons `formData` is a few regular `useState` hooks (e.g. `const [name, setName] = useState("")`. They are set in the input's `onChange` handlers and read in the `value` field (as a side note, I've considered using the `useForm` hook but that should be irrelevant).

Answer (score 6):

While it may be tempting to disable the linter warning for your dependencies, I would suggest not doing that and instead look at alternatives. By disabling the linter, any future updates to your useEffect callback can cause you to miss dependencies that you might actually need to include, leading to bugs with stale values. Below are some alternatives to consider.

#### Removing the `useEffect()`

I would reconsider the need for the `useEffect()` hook in the first place. From the user's perspective, their form data should be saved once they submit the form, or once they click "connect" on the subsequent modal. Both of these actions are user-triggered interactions, and so the saving logic should sit within these interactions' event handlers, and not within an effect. At the moment, your effect serves the purpose of sharing shared logic between your event handlers, which is an unnecessary need for an effect as it can be achieved by creating a shared function. You can remove the effect by putting the shared logic into its own function:

```js
function saveData(userData) {
  submit(formData, userData); // note, you don't need to `await` something if you don't need the function to wait for it to complete
}
```

This shared function can now be used by both of your event handlers - the one that handles the submission of the form itself, and the other that handles the connection and population of your user data from within `ConnectModal`. By using this function, you can "continue" your submission flow from both the modal connect event and the original form submission event. This would mean updating your form submission handler to use this shared function like so:

```js
// Submit click handler
if(userData) {
  saveData(userData); 
} else {
  setShowConnectModal(true);
}
```

It also means updating your `ConnectModal` event handler that sets your `userData` to call the `saveData` function. This can be done by passing through a new prop to `ConnectModal`, eg:

```js
<ConnectModal
  onConnect={saveData}
  setUserData={setUserData}
/>
```

Within your modal component, you can then call `onConnect(...)` with your `userData` that you call `setUserData(...)` with (note, as you haven't shown how `userData` is actually set, I assume you have an event handler in `ConnectModal` that controls this, the below function call to `onConnect()` would sit in there also):

```js
// Connect click handler within ConnectModal
onConnect(newUserData);
```

#### Giving `formData` a "stable identity"

Rather than storing `formData` as a state value, you can look at giving it a stable identity with the [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) hook. A stable identity means that React will always returns the same ref object on every rerender. When an object has this property, then you don't need to include it in your dependency array. Moreover, including it in the dependency array doesn't hurt either as the object isn't changing, so it won't cause the effect to execute. If `formData` doesn't need to influence your UI, then you can swap out its state value with a ref, allowing you to omit it as a dependency:

```js
const formDataRef = useRef(...);
// When you need to set your formData you would use `formDataRef.current = ...`

useEffect(() => {
  if (userData && pendingSubmitIntent) {
    pendingSubmitIntent(false);
    submit(formDataRef.current, userData); // use the ref's `.current` property which holds your formData
  }
}, [pendingSubmitIntent, userData]); // no need to specify the ref as it's stable accross renders
```

#### Using the `useEvent()` hook

While it most likely isn't needed for your case as you can remove the effect (or use `useRef()`), there might be legitimate cases where you need an effect to run on a change of a particular value, but the dependency values that the linter is asking you to add will cause your effect to run too often. In such a case, you can consider using the `useEvent()` hook (it's currently experimental, but you can add a [shim/polyfill](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#internal-implementation) for it if needed). For example, you could do:

```js
const onSubmit = useEvent((userData) => {
  submit(formData, userData);
});

useEffect(() => {
  if (userData && pendingSubmitIntent) {
    pendingSubmitIntent(false);
    onSubmit(userData);
  }
}, [pendingSubmitIntent, userData]);
```

Now the need for specifying `formData` within your effect is no longer needed as it's no longer used within the effect callback. The function provided to `useEvent()` also has access to the "latest" value of `formData` from the surrounding scope. Moreover, the `onSubmit` function returned by the `useEvent()` call is always the same, so it's stable. This means that it doesn't need to be provided as a dependency to the `useEffect()` hook call as you don't risk referring to the wrong `onSubmit` function. You can find more info about [useEvent() here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-event-function).

There are some great articles on [React’s new beta documentation site](https://beta.reactjs.org/) relating to the above suggestions and how to best tackle your issue in different scenarios:

- [Removing Effect Dependencies](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/removing-effect-dependencies)
- [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)
- [Separating Events from Effects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/separating-events-from-effects)

Comment: Thanks for this extensive reply! I've not found time to come back to this, and don't remember why solution 1 didn't work for me. But maybe it actually does and I overcomplicated things. Worst case I'll use the `useRef` solution.

Comment: @User No worries! Even if useRef doesn’t end up working out you can then implement the useEvent hook as a custom hook which will sort out your issue m.

Answer (score 0):

If the user already connected you can continue with the submission in the `submitClickHandler`.

```
const submitClickHandler = useCallback(()=>{
 if(!userData) {
  setShowConnectModal(true)
  return
 }
 (async()=>{
  if(userData && formData){
     await submit(userData && formData)
    }
  })()


},[userData,formData])
```

Otherwise in the `ConnectModal` you will submit the form

First pass the `submit` and 'formData' to `ConnectModal`

```
{showConnectModal && (
 <ConnectModal
    setUserData={setUserData}
    submit={submit}
    formData={formData}
/>
)}
```

Then set the `userData` and `submit` the form in a `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(()=>{

 setUserData(()=>userData)
 
 (async()=>{
   if(userData && formData){
     await submit(userData && formData)
   }
 })()


 },[userData,formData])
```

finally close the modal